# Can't start Hadoop

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

i'm try to install hadoop (single-node) on ubuntu.

I formatted the namenode (After created the folder in hdfs/namenode) with

```
/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/bin sudo hadoop namenode -format
```

It works. Next i was trying to start hadoop with

```
/usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/sbin sudo start-dfs.sh (or start-all.sh)
```

and it always say to me command not found.

I tried to re-format the folder but "command not found", i cant format again. I delete the tmp folder and create it again but nothing.
I tried to use `chmod +x *.sh` as i see on one post but it wont works.
I'm newmbie on ubuntu so explain as much you can , thanks.
Suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last command is not true.

> /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/sbin sudo start-dfs.sh

It should run command :

> /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.0/sbin sudo ./start-dfs.sh

Comment: Error: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.GetConf it cant' load that class

Comment: Thank you too. @DanieleS